SQL - Show total sum along with grouping in a table
How can we show the total sum of table along with group by sum. Here is the table
Table Name - Population
City        Building_no     population
Chicago      5                10
Chicago      6                20
Denver       8                25
Denver       9                30

Output
City       City_Population     Total_Population
Chicago     30                  85
Denver      55                  85

I am able to get City_population with below code -
select city, sum(population) from population group by city

How do i get the column of total_population?

if you are using MySQL, MariaDB etc you can use WITH ROLLUP, but recommend restricting the tags to the SQL implementation (and version) you actually use.

You could use a subquery as a column:
  SELECT city,
         SUM(population),
         (SELECT SUM(population)
            FROM population) AS the_total
    FROM population
GROUP BY city;

Or use a subquery in the FROM statement:
  SELECT a.city,
         SUM(a.population),
         b.total_population
    FROM population a,
         (SELECT SUM(population) AS total_population
            FROM population) b
GROUP BY a.city,
         b.total_population;

Although the second option may look more complex, you may get better results with bigger tables, since - I believe - the subquery will be run only once, while using the subquery in the SELECT statement will probably need to be run for each row.

Don't jump to conclusions, a decent optimizer realizes the SELECT list subquery only needs to be run once. Anyway, when in doubt, check the explain/execution plan.

Use SUM() window function, first partition by city, then for for the whole table.
select distinct city,
                sum(population) over (partition by city) City_Population,
                sum(population) over () Total_Population
from yourtable;

ANSI/ISO SQL-2023, optional feature "T611, Elementary OLAP operations"

You can use a window function on top of normal aggregation. Note that this is more efficient than the other answer using distinct.
select
  t.city,
  sum(t.population) as City_Population,
  sum(sum(t.population)) over () as Total_Population
from yourtable t
group by
  t.city;

